# cosine similarity search with non-english text giving wrong results

Tags: nlp, embedded, semantics, cosine-similarity

I am trying to perform cosine similarity search using non english text.

```
pdf_file = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/India_Hindi.pdf", 'rb')

pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)

pdf_text = ""

for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
    page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
    pdf_text += page.extract_text()

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")

sentences = pdf_text.split(".")
sentence_embeddings = embed(sentences)


# Perform vector search
query = "प्र�तस्था�पत"
query_embedding = embed([query])

# Calculate cosine similarity between the query embedding and all sentence embeddings
similarities = cosine_similarity(query_embedding, sentence_embeddings)

# Find the most similar sentences based on cosine similarity
most_similar_idx = similarities.argsort()[0][::-1]  # Sort in descending order
top_k = 5  # Number of top results to retrieve

# Print the top-k most similar sentences
for idx in most_similar_idx[:top_k]:
    print
```

(sentences[idx])

I have two problems

1. Hindi characters it's not recognizing and taking it as some bad symbols. As you can see in above query
2. Search results are not so good. example I search for "मूलवंश" but what I am getting is as below though there is exact match in the document

   ट�
   ]] �सिक्कम
   �ववर�णयां
   *      *        *         *]
   37
   �नवर्चन

What I want to do

1. How do I input Hindi text with correct characters
2. Any suggestion for improving the search result